# installing newest ckeditor + wiris plugin

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I've installing the newest ckeditor. but I've difficulties in configure wiris plugin on them.
I've try the steps listed on wiris website. but I've difficulties in editing `configuration.ini`.

Please help me editing configuration.ini and give example `configuration.ini` that works.
I'll so appreciated if anyone can give the download link containing ckeditor folder + wiris plugin already installed.

Answer (score 0):

WIRIS plugin works without any configuration.ini file (from 3.50.x version onwards) using its default values. You only have to include a configuration.ini file if you need like to customize the configuration. There is a configuration.ini.dist in your ckeditor_wiris directory you can use as an example. You need to remove the leading # to uncomment variables. You can find more details at http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/resources/configuration-table
You can also download this working demo: http://www.wiris.com/plugins/demo/ckeditor/php/